# Django, Права на удаление записи

Tags: django, права, права-доступа

Есть приложение на Django4 типа блог, View на основе классов. Редактирование чужих записей запретил переопределив функцию get_form_kwargs: из класса UpdateView

```
`def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    if self.request.user != kwargs['instance'].author:
        return self.handle_no_permission()
    return kwargs `
```

Для CreateView переопределил функцию form_valid:

```
`def form_valid(self, form):
    """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form) `
```

А как запретить в классе DeleteView доступ на удаление всем кроме автора?

```
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_list.html'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')


class ArticleEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_edit.html'
    permission_denied_message = 'Доступ закрыт'
    fields = ['title', 'body']
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        if self.request.user != kwargs['instance'].author:
            return self.handle_no_permission()
        return kwargs


class ArticleDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.object.author != self.request.user:
            return redirect('login')
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        self.object.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)

#    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.object != self.request.user:
            return redirect('login')
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        self.object.delete() #


class ArticleDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_detail.html'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')


class ArticleCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_new.html'
    fields = ['title', 'body']
    login_url = 'login'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: переопределить метод `delete` пробовали? в `ArticleDeleteView`

Comment: пробовал. Консоль выдаёт:  DeleteView использует FormMixin для обработки запросов на публикацию. Как следствие, любая пользовательская логика удаления в обработчике ArticleDeleteView.delete() должна быть перемещена в form_valid().  Пробовал переоределить form_valid, не работает. Может неправильно переопределяю form_valid? Она в коде выше, закомментирована.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin

Answer (score 0):

```
class ArticleDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
model = Articles
template_name = 'edit_page.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('edit_page')
success_msg = 'Запись удалена'
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    messages.success(self.request, self.success_msg)
    return super().post(request)

def form_valid(self, form):
    if self.object.author != self.request.user:
        return redirect('login_page')
    self.object.delete()
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login_page')
    success_msg = 'Запись не удалена!!'
    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url, success_msg)
```

не удалось только сообщение получить

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).